# Seeking Book about Aerodynamic Design of the Space Shuttle

Tags: space-shuttle, reentry, aerodynamics, reference-request

a few years ago I found a book written by an engineer working on the aerodynamics of the shuttle during design, ALT, and early STS.  I have since forgotten the title and author's name.  Does that sound familiar to someone, can you provide the title and author name?

Thanks, PT